# 3D using VR headset in Nokia 3

Tags: google-cardboard, stereo-video, nokia-3

So let's say I have got a split screen 3D video. My Google search results told me that if I just play it in VLC in my Nokia 3 and use a VR headset, I will get 3D experience. However when I play 360 degrees VR videos from Google, they are distorted and not rectangle in shape. So I am afraid that when I play rectangular side by side 3D videos, the videos will be distorted and the sides will be missing. So what should I do to convert the side by side video to the distorted VR like video? Is there any app or something?

I have not tried them yet as my VR headset has not yet arrived but I want to have everything ready as soon my VR arrives. (Basically I have decided to wait for some time and if I cannot watch 3D with cardboard I might not buy it)

Screenshot of how video should look like when seen by google cardboard(i.e. what I meant by distorted video)
[image]

And this is what 3D split screen loos like and I intend to convert this to above form :[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a player like **[3D VR Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mj.govrshadow)** to play the video..

There are many such *VR Player* apps in Play Store (search for it). All you need to do is download the right one you need.

Comment: Now that I have my VR headset, your app is not working. It is not callibrated and has no option to callibrate. I need something to scan my QR code and callibrate.

Comment: What is your VR model?

Comment: Here's the VR headset and the QR code :
https://teslaandi.wordpress.com/2016/01/22/vr-box-2-0-qr-code-and-vague-review/
And yeah thanks man for all your time.

Comment: Also note that I got it callibrated on Google cardboard app but that doesn't  not play 3D videos